# Quitar diccionarios de una lista

Tags: python

Les expreso mi problema.
Tengo un archivo txt que tiene diccionarios.
Adjunto unos diccionarios de ejemplo:

```
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":781,"Andalucía":202,"Canarias":330}} #Comentario1
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Error":474,"Reconfig":102,"Data":3}} #ERROR
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":15,"Andalucía":82,"Canarias":37}} #Comentario2
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":0.0515,"Andalucía":802,"Canarias":0.137}} #Comentario3
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Error":744,"Reconfig":052,"Data":7}} #ERROR2
```

Yo tengo un programa que cuenta las líneas, en este caso son 5. No obstante, lo que quiero es que cuente solo los diccionarios relevantes, que no hayan sufrido error, entonces quiero que al contar las líneas del archivo txt. cuente 3. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Python tiene el operador `in` para saber si cierta palabra está o no en una cadena. Así que puedes usar `if "Error" in linea` para saber si tienes que contar o no esa línea.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Se me olvidó comentar. como tenía que leer el archivo txt guarde los diccionarios en una lista, entonces creo que la funcion que comentas: if "Error" in linea, no me valdría pues la estoy utilizando pero da error

Comment: En este caso `linea` sería cada uno de los elementos de tu lista, es decir, deberías usar un bucle de tipo `for linea in lista`. Por otro lado si ahora cada "linea" es un diccionario en vez de una cadena, puedes aplicar una solución un poco chapuza, pero simple, que es convertirlo de nuevo en cadena para buscar en él, es decir, hacer `if "Error" in str(linea)`

Comment: Gracias por responder. Tengo esto, pero me sigue saltando error: 
`for linea in lista:
    if "APN" in str(linea)
  Total_Lineas=Total_Lineas-1`

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open("tu_archivo.txt") as archivo:
    sin_error = [linea.strip() for linea in archivo.readlines() if "ERROR" not in linea]
    print(f"Lineas sin errores: {len(sin_error)}\n")
    print("\n".join(sin_error))
```

Resultado:

```
Lineas sin errores: 3

{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":781,"Andalucía":202,"Canarias":330}} #Comentario1
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":15,"Andalucía":82,"Canarias":37}} #Comentario2
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":0.0515,"Andalucía":802,"Canarias":0.137}} #Comentario3
```

Comment: Eso es justo lo que buscaba. ¿Pero habría alguna forma de guardar esas líneas sin errores en otro fichero? Yo probé con esto: `with open("archivoSINerrores.txt","w") as fname:
  fname.write(str(sin_error))` pero el problema es que en lugar de guardarme las líneas de forma ordenada me guarda todo junto y un poco caótico

Comment: @Logan Recuerda que `sin_error` es una lista de strings. Utiliza `fname.write("\n".join(sin_error))` para guardarlas con saltos de línea.